# Number of Style for Image Added into Post

Tags: images

When adding an image [through the GUI](https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Images_in_Posts_and_Pages), an `HTML` element is created:

```
<img src="http://example.com/images/leaf.jpg" 
alt="leaf graphic" 
title="leaf graphic" 
class="alignright size-medium wp-image-3109" 
height="25" width="30"/>
```

A sequential `3109` and a style name `wp-image-3109` (?) is generated.

Besides, I cannot find it in any table in the DB (`wp_posts`, `wp_postmeta` or any other table). 
How the next ID must be generated? Is there a WP PHP function returning it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not sure if I understand your question correctly, but...

In WP any attachment is a post (of attachment type). So 3109 is ID of that post.

This means, that if you’ll take a look at wp_posts table, then you should find that post and there should be some additional info stored as meta fields in wp_postmeta table (for example sizes of all generated images are stored as meta).

So the ID of next uploaded image will be the next value of ID column in wp_posts table.

Comment: I checked the DB `wp_posts`, `wp_postmeta` and other tables and i was unable to find these numbers. What i think is that these numbers were at some moment valid ID posts, and then the original objects were deleted... Hence... why WP uses those style IDs? Are them defined at some place with these numbers?

Comment: So maybe you’re checking wrong DB or wrong tables.